# Maps Marker click targets wrong marker

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, typescript

so I create several Google Maps Marker through a loop and add click listener which are supposed to open the corresponding infoWindow. However every marker click always opens the infoWindow of the marker that was added last.

```
private loadMarkers():void {
    net.Ajax.getJson("/locations.json", (response:Location[]) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            var location:Location = response[i];
            var marker:google.maps.Marker = this.createMarker(location);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
                this.onMarkerClicked(marker);
            });
        }
    });
}

private onMarkerClicked(marker:google.maps.Marker):void {
    this.infoWindow.close();

    this.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: marker.getTitle()
    });

    this.infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic closure conceptual mistake. Closures capture the variable `marker` not its value. And since variable scope is by `function` you only have one `marker`.

Fix : create an `immediately executing function` (similar to `module pattern` in typescript).

```
net.Ajax.getJson("/locations.json", (response:Location[]) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            (function(){
            var location:Location = response[i];
            var marker:google.maps.Marker = this.createMarker(location);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
                this.onMarkerClicked(marker);
            });
            })();
        }
    });
```

PS: I have a video on the subject : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hU4cbxpe49Y&hd=1